# shows system menu when user click in each row of a verticalfield manager

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

My application using a 'vertical field' manager and i add some text to it using a custonField class.The vertical manager constructor is:

```java
scrollingRegion = new VerticalFieldManager(
        USE_ALL_HEIGHT| VERTICAL_SCROLL | VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR|USE_ALL_WIDTH);
```

I also craete menu using:

```java
protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int context) {
    menu.add(_imageMenuItem);
    //super.makeMenu(menu, context);
}
```

```java
class ImageMenuItem extends MenuItem {
    /**
     * Creates a new MenuDemoMenuItem object
     */
    ImageMenuItem() {
        super("Login Screen", 0, 0);
    }
    public boolean onMenu(int i) {
        return false;
    }

    public void run() {
        UiApplication app = (UiApplication) getApplication();
        app.pushScreen(new LoginScreen());
    }
}
```

My problem is when I click in the vertical field(which uses a table row manager), the menu is displayed. How can I avoid it? Can any one suggest a solution

Answer (score 1):

if the item is ButtonField you can consume click by define it in the constructor

```
ButtonField btn = new ButtonField("Login", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
```